# Does replaying missions in Starcraft II earn extra credits?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I were to replay an earlier mission in the campaign that rewarded me credits when it was initially completed, would it reward me credits again?  This would be useful if I wanted to farm up all the upgrades available to me instead of being required to pick and choose between them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't earn credits from repeating missions, but you can unlock achievements and earn research. Achievements unlock decals and avatars.

Reference:

- [GameSpot Forums](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/strategy/starcraft2/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-55808402&pid=939643)

Comment: If I am not mistaken though whatever equipment you had when you first played that mission is all you ever have in it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I've finished all missions before going to Char and found that replaying some missions gives about 200k credits.

For instance, after replaying Breakout mission (I was out to get some unearned achievements) I've got credits when visited Research console.

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe you do not get the credits for completing the mission itself. You do get any research points (if you missed it the first time), and you can then sell the research for 10k per point if your research is capped out.

Comment: @Wikwocket, I knew that, but I'm getting 200k+ after every missing I've replayed (except for a few I've got nothing after). Also I never missed any research points. (And there is no research points to earn in Breakout mission, for instance.) So it can't be just research points. (Although it says about research points when rewarding me with credits!)

Answer (score 0):

He's talking about the credits you spend on upgrades. You earn them for completing missions and from completing certain bonus mission objectives. The exception is the Protoss missions, but those grant extra research to offset that.